# Suggestions on making the text more visible or readable

Tags: html, css, text, background, photo

I have this photo on my website which looks like this:

[image: Cover]

I tried putting a shadow to the text and it would look like this:

[image: WithShadow]

The problem is that it looks a bit odd with the shadow.

Any suggestions on how could I make it more readable **without** changing the color of the text and the background?

Comment: Change the text to white and put a filter over the image or keep the text the same colour and give the text a light background for contrast.

Comment: Give the text a background color?

Comment: @ovokuro what do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using an all round text shadow:

```css
.text {
  padding:5px;
  background: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), -1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">some test text</div>
```

With the above, you can change the opacity of the shadow to make it more / less prominent

Comment: I guess I could use this one, Thanks bud

Answer (score 3):

This answer makes the assumption that your markup is something like this:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Here are a few methods you can try:

**Give the text a background...**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

**Add a subtle gradient behind the text...**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, .6));
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

**Add a text shadow...**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

**Bigger font size, extra weight, uppercase...**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

**Overlay behind text with opacity...**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

p:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a white stroke to the text by adding this:

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
```

Or if you can, add a semi-transparent background

Comment: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke